# Linear regression: explanation of slope constraints

Tags: regression

I am given regression equations, one showing linear regression of x on y, and the other y on x. Both refer to the **same set of data-points**.

```
4X - 5Y + 33 = 0
20X - 9Y - 107 = 0
```

- Taking the first to be X (dependent) on Y (independent) => of the form `X = a + bY`.
  I end up with slope value of 1.25
- Taking the second to be Y (dependent) on X (independent) => of the form `Y = a + bX`.
  I end up with slope value of 2.22

Now, these values **somehow imply** that the system of regression lines is *invalid*? How is that? I am unable to visualize this.

The book states the "rule" being that:

1. Both coefficients (slopes) must be less than 1
2. Both coefficients (slopes) must be of the same sign

Are these correct? What other constraints exist for a set of regression equations to be valid?

Comment: "*I am told both regression coefficients cannot exceed 1.*" -- don't believe everything you're told. Were they perhaps talking about standardized coefficients?

Comment: The book I am studying says "But this is not possible because both the regression coefficients are greater than 1. Hence, we will now treat eq.1 as Y on X and eq.2 as X on Y. "

Comment: This seems rather strange. Which book? Are you *sure* they're not talking about standardized coefficients?

Comment: Introductory Statistical Methods by S.P. Gupta (not the most popular of textbooks). I don't know what you mean by standardized coeffs. If that implies the Y-intercept on the lines is 0, it isn't so.

Comment: Either the book is wrong, or you've misunderstood it. Post the _complete_ text relating to your question.

Comment: I've updated the question, with better context.

Comment: I'm guessing the rule arises from constraints on the correlation coefficient, which is the square root of the product of the two regression coefficients.

Comment: Can you give more of the context from this book? How would a rule about correlation imply a constraint on one slope coefficient? Certainly, if one regression coefficient is above 1 the coefficient of the regression with predictor and response interchanged will be smaller than 1, but if you're talking about least squares regression (rather than population calculations involving conditional means), the assumptions of at least one of the two regressions will be violated. Perhaps you could edit to clarify your question further.

Answer (score 2):

> I am told both regression coefficients cannot exceed 1

Well, yes they can. There are no constraints about values of coefficients. Where did you get it from? The slope is simply the tangent of the angle between your line and OX axis, so it can get any value in $\mathbb{R}$

The only trivial "constraint" is that given simple linear regression from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, if you look at the equations 
$$ y=ax+b$$ 
and
$$ x=cy+e$$
Then at least one of the $\{a,c\}$ has an absolute value not greater then $1$.

Assuming that $a\neq 0$
$$y=ax+b \iff -ax=b-y \iff x=\frac{-y}{-a}+\frac{b}{-a} \iff x = \frac{y}{a} - \frac{b}{a} \iff x = \frac{1}{a}y - \frac{b}{a}$$

so $c=\frac{1}{a}$, and as a result, if $|a|>1$ then $|c|=\left |\frac{1}{a}\right | < 1$

Comment: Shouldn't there be some constraint on the slopes of regression lines y on x and vice versa? One is a reflection of the other about the x = y line is it not?

Comment: But what do you mean by "regression lines y on x and vice versa"? You mean running regression (what kind of? OLS?) once with X as input and Y as output and once the other way around, or you mean expressing the simple linear equation once in the form $y=ax+b$ and once in $x=cy+d$?

Comment: in the first case, this depends on the data and used loss function, in the second one it is simple to show that $y=ax+b \iff -ax=b-y \iff x=\frac{-y}{-a}+\frac{b}{-a} \iff x = \frac{y}{a} - \frac{b}{a} \iff x = \frac{1}{a}y - \frac{b}{a}$ (assuming $a\neq 0$)

Comment: We are given 2 equations. One is X on Y and the other is Y on X with the same data-set. We are to ascertain which is which. It is simple linear regression.

Comment: There is no such thing as $X$ or $Y$, you can name your axis whatever you want, even "elephant" and "big bang". You need to put some definition what do you consider as $X$ and $Y$. from above equation you can see, that absolute value of the slope of one of this lines will be not greater then $1$, but it does not mean, that this has to be $X$ on $Y$ or vice versa

Comment: When I say X on Y, I mean Y is the independent variable and X is the dependent one. We are forming 2 equations; one with X considered independent, and the other with Y, in order to get 2 regression coefficients.

Comment: AFAIK "dependent" and "independent" have **no meaning** when talking about line equation.

Comment: It says [here](http://explorable.com/linear-regression-analysis) that they do.

Comment: No, it does not. You are missing a point here. These are names **you give** them in terms of operation. This is not something that can be "retrived", because it is not the particular data feature, it is the parameter of process you are applying.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, about the lines themselves not having this property. I am focussing here on the system of lines as a whole, and not one. I have updated the question for clarity.